# Yii widget time picker - not able to pre-select the value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I have a time picker in my page. For this I used the following Yii widget. I couldn't able to populate the value dynamically .

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTimePicker',
    array(
        'model' =>$Visits,
        'name' => "l_tme",
        'id'=>"l_time_id",
         'value' => $time_in_date,
        'noAppend' => true, 
        'options' => array(
            'disableFocus' => FALSE,
            'showMeridian' => TRUE 
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=> array('class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width:90px;','id'=>'l_tme_add'),
     )
);
```

Following Script code I have used.

```
var s_val = '12:34:00 AM';
document.getElementById('l_time_id').value = s_val;
```

I have called the above script on page load.

But the value is not populated in the field. Please help me

Comment: 'id'=>'l_tme_add'), ... I can see it is misspelled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `id` from `htmlOptions` and keep your widget code the same.

`'htmlOptions'=> array('class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width:90px;'),`

After the document is loaded i.e. `document.ready()`,  write the same code -

`var s_val = '12:34:00 AM';
document.getElementById('l_time_id').value = s_val;`

The value will be displayed in the timepicker fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding default value from PHP side:

```
'htmlOptions' => [
    'value' => '12:34:00 AM',
    ...
]
```

Comment: '12:34:00 AM' is the dynamic value. I need to populate this using script.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to set the value of the time picker this way

you have to follow doc at

http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

$('#timepicker').timepicker('setTime', '12:45 AM');

also you have to be sure you are doing this after document is ready

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value *in the model you are using for this form* rather than in the widget itself.

For example:

**In your controller:**

```
$model = new YourActiveRecordModel();
$model->l_tme = date_format(new DateTime(),'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$this->render('your_view_file',array('model'=>$model));
```